# Posting on facebook fanpage as page via app [access token issue]

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently creating webpage, where user can add news to his page. I want to allow him to add same news to his fb fan page as page itself. Here is the code responsible for it ( working ):

```
        $access_token =  'my_access_token';
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET');
        $page_id = 1;

        $session = new FacebookSession($access_token);
        $page_access_token = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/'.$page_id, array( 'fields' => 'access_token' ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

        $params =  array(
            'name'          => 'test',
            'description'   => 'hellooo',
            'message'       => 'bleble',
            'caption'       => 'test',
            'picture'       => '',
            'published'     => true,
        );
        $params['access_token'] = $page_access_token['access_token'];

        $post = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/'.$page_id.'/feed', $params))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

the problem is actually that access token expires. User of this application is not going to use it very often, but through a long time.

Is there any way to generate dynamically this token right before posting anything to wall?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getLongLivedSession` on the `FacebookSession` class...

> Returns a new Facebook\FacebookSession resulting from extending a short-lived access token. This method will make a network request. If you know you already have a long-lived session, you do not need to call this. The only time you get a short-lived session as of March 2014 is from the Facebook SDK for JavaScript. If this session is not short-lived, this method will return $this. A long-lived session is on the order of months. A short-lived session is on the order of hours. You can figure out whether a session is short-lived or long-lived by checking the expiration date in the session info, but it's not a precise thing.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0

You do have to renew them eventually by re-authorizing the user.

Comment: I've assigned result from this method to $session variable,buuut... I still get error "Error validating access token: Session has expired [..]"

Comment: when it expires you need to re-authenticate the user (i.e. they have to log in through facebook to your app again)